# Quantile Normalization output

Tags: r, normalization, quantile

I am trying to do quantile normalization of a data. I tried to write output to a table but it is giving me just one column. Can anyone suggest a solution

test.txt

```
ID  IID G9  G3  G3A G30 G32 G33 G34 G35
1509    5   0   0   0   0   0   88  88  88
1506    11  0   0   0   0   0   88  88  88
339 26  7   0   0   58  0   11  0   .
1104    33  0   41  0   0   0   88  88  88
1407    68  0   35  0   0   0   11  0   28
442 75  1   45  35  49  0   88  88  88
1509    80  0   0   0   0   0   16  0   30
527 86  0   0   0   0   0   88  88  88
170 89  2   0   0   0   0   88  88  88
```

Code:

```
x <- read.table("test.txt",header=T)

x <- data.matrix(x[,3:10])
hist(x, main="Selected dataset")

x_transformed <- qqnorm(x, plot.it =F)$x
hist(x_transformed, breaks=10, main="Selected transformed datset")

write.table(x_transformed, file="transformedile.txt", sep="\t" , quote=F, row.names=F)
```

Result:

```
x
-2.46012433756
-2.03683413170139
0.528399301498654
-1.81551733495267
-1.65847206103563
0.122153088902552
-1.53412054435255
-1.42978833594552
0.192663868219727
```